# Xpath for selecting inner text of an element

Tags: xpath

I need to select the following element on a webpage

```
< td colspan = "1" >
< span class="text-left">
<strong>QTY Total
</strong></span>
<span style = "float: right;" >
< strong > 20.99 </ strong >
</ span > 
</ td >
```

The element I need to extract is the 20.99 text which is a child element

I have tried the following to locate the element and it returns nothing

```
$x("//*[@style='float: right;' and contains(text(), '20.99')]")
```

I tried two locate the element using the following

```
$x("//*[@style='float: right;']")
```

But this locates to elements with the same style.

Does anybody know an Xpath I can try which will locate the 20.99?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first XPath the "20.99" text is the child `strong`. So you have to use that in the `contains(...)` clause like

```
//*[@style='float: right;' and contains(strong/text(), '20.99')]/strong
```

Probably an even better XPath would be searching explicitly for `span` elements

```
//span[@style='float: right;' and contains(strong/text(), '20.99')]/strong
```

which also works.
Both select the `strong` element child of a `span` element with the text "20.99".

> The element I need to extract is the 20.99 text

To get the `text()` node of the `strong` tag append a `/text()` to the expressions:

Answer (score 3):

Using text() is usually wrong: the predicate `[contains(text(), 'xyz')]` is almost always better written as `[contains(., 'xyz')]`.

That's because `.` (which here is equivalent to `string(.)`) selects the content of the context element as a string regardless of any nested elements, comments etc, whereas `text()` only looks at immediate text node children.

Comment: Will it find only elements with the exact match (i.e. `xyz`), or also those that contain more then just that (e.g. `abcxyz`, or `xyzabc`)?